# Jetpack Compose how to create an ImageBitmap with specific size and configurations?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

ImageBitmap loads and image with

```
ImageBitmap.imageResource(
        LocalContext.current.resources,
        R.drawable.landscape1
    )
```

also it there is a function which can be invoked with some parameters

```
ImageBitmap(
        width = 300,
        height = 300,
        config = ImageBitmapConfig.Argb8888,
        hasAlpha = true,
        colorSpace = ColorSpaces.Srgb
    )
```

it returns and empty bitmap with no pixel data, is it possible to create an imageBitMap with some specific configurations?

Is there something like for ImageBitmap?

```
val option = BitmapFactory.Options()
option.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
val bitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    LocalContext.current.resources,
    R.drawable.landscape1,
    option
)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can convert `Bitmap` to `ImageBitmap`:

```
val option = BitmapFactory.Options()
option.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    LocalContext.current.resources,
    R.drawable.test,
    option
).asImageBitmap()
```

Note, that it'll take significant amount of time on each recomposition, so you'd probably want to wrap it with `remember`

Comment: Your answer is valid but since there is a similar function for ImageBitmap that has configurations, i wonder if there is one for ImageBitmap without any conversion. And what's the point of having empty ImageBitmap anyways?

Comment: @Thracian The only usage of that fun I found is [this](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/621ce0f19d03629a241d0a0f1137d35c441db6e5/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/Border.kt#L195). Looks like it just meant to create an empty bitmap to be used for canvas in future. Anyway if you look into the sources of both `ImageBitmap(width, height, ..)` and `asImageBitmap()` you'll see that `ImageBitmap` is just a wrapper for `Bitmap`.